# Convert html to LaTeX using Python

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, latex, lxml

What is an effective way to convert a number of html files to LaTeX? Because I need to use special constructs and environments, conditional on `css` classes, and I want to fine-tune the final .tex file, I don't want to use a standard converter (such as `pandoc` or any other ready-made converter). Instead, I'd like to build my own Python3 script, but being relatively new to this language I wonder where I should start from. I've given a look to `lxml` and Beautiful Soup, and I wonder if they can be a good starting point.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/167523/html-to-latex-how-can-i-use-python-and-lxml-to-convert-an-html-document-to-late

Comment: Thanks, I've already seen it, but unfortunately could not get much out of it. I can't understand how the example can be changed to parse an external file and print out to another file or to stdout. When I tried, it gave me a lot of errors

Comment: Perhaps [pandoc](https://pandoc.org/)?

Comment: The "best" way of doing something? The "best" strategy? I don't know. That is very hard to answer. I think you should try to ask a more concrete, specific, practical question. Show us what you have tried, provide a [mcve]. See also https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask.

Comment: You're right, and after all I am not looking for anythin "best", I just need to find a reasonable way to start and solve my problem. I've edited the question accordingly

Comment: The question is still too broad. You want to find "a reasonable way to start and solve my problem". OK. But what exactly is your problem?

Comment: The mentioned stackexchange was exactly what I was looking for. Easily customizable, good structure and lots of flexibility for parsing. I don't know why you had problems with it.